# How to prevent internet explorer of being reinstalled? How to delete IE completely?

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet-explorer, uninstall, blocking

I have Windows 7. I tried to remove IE completely. However, windows itself always allows it to be reinstalled again:

By going to the option "Set Program Defaults" one can always install IE again:

[image]

How can I prevent this?

Which files are responsible for this (re)installation and can I remove them? Can I change some things in the registry to prevent this?

My ultimate goal is to remove IE completely and prevent users of reinstalling it. Hence, not so clean solution... like sabotaging some registry files or deleting particular files are also acceptable (as long as they are not restored by a reinstall).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out this link once - http://www.wikihow.com/Uninstall-Internet-Explorer-Completely

Comment: Dear Pankaj, I went through that process and downgraded IE11 to IE8. Ending up with IE8 it was no longer in the "update list" so I had to remove it elsewhere. The only place to delete it was in the menu "Turn on/off windows compenents" (=translation) in the "Programs" section. However, that menu also allows it to be enabled again...

Comment: Try denying permission to

c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe

Comment: Eventually, the user of the computer will have administrator privileges and can undo this permission block. Ideally, the user of the computer must be able to have internet access (e.g. online databases), must be able to install his own software etc... but must not be allowed to surf on the internet (i.e. by installing IE)

Comment: Check this link too and tell me does this help?

http://www.techsupportalert.com/how_to_disable_internet_explorer.htm

Comment: Internet Explorer is a Windows core component. Only its GUI can be removed. You also cannot give admin rights to a user and expect to effectively restrict his permissions at the same time.

Comment: @kristof2014 - If the user will have Administrator rights, any thing you do, will mean that user can enable Internet Explorer since it will remain in the `Component Store` and I highly recommend NOT removing it.  Besides if they have `Administrator` rights they could just add it back even if it was removed.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I understands the risks, but is there perhaps a way to "sabotage" IE (mess up some registry keys), so that it wont start (and even a reinstall won't fix the keys)

Comment: You could always install Linux.